# PostgreSQL: improving pg_dump, pg_restore performance

Tags: performance, postgresql, backup, restore

When I began, I used `pg_dump` with the default plain format.  I was unenlightened.

Research revealed to me time and file size improvements with `pg_dump -Fc | gzip -9 -c > dumpfile.gz`.  I was enlightened.

When it came time to create the database anew,

```
# create tablespace dbname location '/SAN/dbname';
# create database dbname tablespace dbname;
# alter database dbname set temp_tablespaces = dbname;

% gunzip dumpfile.gz              # to evaluate restore time without a piped uncompression
% pg_restore -d dbname dumpfile   # into a new, empty database defined above
```

I felt unenlightened:  the restore took 12 hours to create the database that's only a fraction of what it will become:

```
# select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('dbname'));
47 GB
```

Because there are predictions this database will be a few terabytes, I need to look at improving performance now.

Please, enlighten me.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

First check that you are getting reasonable IO performance from your disk setup. Then check that you PostgreSQL installation is appropriately tuned. In particular `shared_buffers` should be set correctly, `maintenance_work_mem` should be increased during the restore, `full_page_writes` should be off during the restore, `wal_buffers` should be increased to 16MB during the restore, `checkpoint_segments` should be increased to something like 16 during the restore, you shouldn't have any unreasonable logging on (like logging every statement executed), `auto_vacuum` should be disabled during the restore.

If you are on 8.4 also experiment with parallel restore, the --jobs option for pg_restore.

Comment: If you have a slave connected, and the load on the master is already considerable, then you may want to just do the backup on the slave instead. Especially since the slave is read-only, I imagine that may also help to some degree. In a large cluster, it may help to have one or more slaves dedicated to staggered backup's if the backups take a long time. So that you don't miss anything, you would want these standby's connected via streaming replication so they get written to from the WAL on the master.

Comment: `shared_buffers should be set correctly` what that mean?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza — I came across the following document about [`shared_buffers`](https://www.postgresqlco.nf/en/doc/param/shared_buffers/) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 56):

## Improve pg dump&restore

PG_DUMP | always use format-directory and `-j` options

```
time pg_dump -j 8 -Fd -f /tmp/newout.dir fsdcm_external
```

PG_RESTORE | always use tuning for postgres.conf and format-directory and `-j` options

```
work_mem = 32MB
shared_buffers = 4GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
full_page_writes = off
autovacuum = off
wal_buffers = -1
```

```shell
time pg_restore -j 8 --format=d -C -d postgres /tmp/newout.dir/
```

Comment: configuration parameters used here improved performance significantly

Comment: Wow! This helped me so much! Thank you!

Comment: Also as well as changing these parameters helped me a lot `maintenance_work_mem = 4GB` `max_wal_size = 4GB`. The time of pg_restore was reduced from 90 mins to 20 mins

Answer (score 14):

Two issues/ideas:

1. By specifying -Fc, the pg_dump output is already compressed.  The compression is not maximal, so you may find some space savings by using "gzip -9", but I would wager it's not enough to warrant the extra time (and I/O) used compressing and uncompressing the -Fc version of the backup.
2. If you are using PostgreSQL 8.4.x you can potentially speed up the restore from a -Fc backup with the new pg_restore command-line option "-j n" where n=number of parallel connections to use for the restore.  This will allow pg_restore to load more than one table's data or generate more than one index at the same time.

Comment: We are currently at 8.3; new reason to upgrade.

Comment: You can use the 8.4 version of pg_restore with an 8.3 version of the server. Just make sure you use pg_dump from 8.3.

Comment: Bah.  We are stuck at 8.3 because we use the Solaris10 package install of Postgres and, "there is no plan to integrate PG8.4 into S10 at this moment." [Ref. http://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-general@postgresql.org/msg136829.html]

I would have to take on the task of installing and maintaining the open-source postgres.  Unsure if we can do that here...

Feh.

Answer (score 11):

I assume you need backup, not a major upgrade of database.

For backup of large databases you should setup [continuous archiving](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/continuous-archiving.html) instead of `pg_dump`.

1. [Set up WAL archiving](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-ARCHIVING-WAL).
2. Make your base backups for example every day by using

   ```
   psql template1 -c "select pg_start_backup('`\`date +%F-%T\``')"
   rsync -a --delete /var/lib/pgsql/data/ /var/backups/pgsql/base/
   psql template1 -c "select pg_stop_backup()"
   ```

A restore would be as simple as restoring database and WAL logs not older than `pg_start_backup` time from backup location and starting Postgres. And it will be much faster.

Comment: We didn't look at PITR (WAL archiving) because the system is not very transaction heavy but will retain many historical records instead.  However, now that I think about it, a more "incremental" backup may help matters.

I shall investigate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
zcat dumpfile.gz | pg_restore -d db_name
```

Removes the full write of the uncompressed data to disk, which is currently your bottleneck.

Answer (score 3):

As you may have guessed simply by the fact that compressing the backup results in faster performance, your backup is I/O bound.  This should come as no surprise as backup is pretty much always going to be I/O bound. Compressing the data trades I/O load for CPU load, and since most CPUs are idle during monster data transfers, compression comes out as a net win.

So, to speed up backup/restore times, you need faster I/O. Beyond reorganizing the database to not be one huge single instance, that's pretty much all you can do.

Comment: If optimizing just the pg_dump time, with parallel dump as of v9.3, compression >0 can hurt a lot! This is because pg_dump and postmaster processes already hog the CPU enough that the addition of compression >=1 makes the overall task significantly CPU-bound instead of I/O-bound. Basically, the older assumption that the CPUs are idle without compression is invalid with parallel dump.

Answer (score 3):

If you're facing issues with the speed of `pg_restore` check whether you dumped your data using `INSERT` or `COPY` statement.

If you use `INSERT` (`pg_dump` is called with `--column-inserts` parameter) the restore of data would be significantly slower.

Using `INSERT` is good for making dumps that are loaded into non-Postgres databases. But if you do a restore to Postgres omit using `--column-inserts` parameter when using `pg_dump`.